# Location of the log for Windows first logon commands

Tags: windows, deployment, unattended, logon-scripts

I have PowerShell script that's set up to run as the first logon command via the unattend.xml file. The script actually does run on the first logon but I would like to know if somewhere I can find the logs from the script execution i.e. output from Write-Verbose/Write-Output/Write-Host etc. from the script execution in some logs. The Unattend logs (Windows\Panther\Unattend) don't actually have the logon command execution logs and I'm not sure of another place to look for these logs.
I will probably just write the logs to a file during script execution if there isn't a better way to get execution trace logs. Appreciate any help. TIA!

Comment: I wouldn't assume that the unattend process will be logging output from your script, so it's probably best for you to handle the logging on your own inside it.